# Connect postgres database with qt without pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, qt

I am new in Qt. Is possible to use mydb1. db in Qt. I have mydb1.db database file and i want to use to insert data without open pgadmin Or terminal.

Comment: You don't connect to a file with Postgres, you connect to a server. If `mydb1.db` is indeed a file that would seem to indicate you are working with SQLite.  If you want to connect to a Postgres server then you will need to use the QT [Driver](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html).

Comment: If you want to use a database instead of, say, reading and writing to a simple text file then you will need to host that DB on a server. It doesn't matter much if you're using PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, ... -- there needs to be some sort of program that loads and parses your DB file and then answers your SQL queries.